# Label not updating when passing string between tabs in UITabViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am a beginner of iOS and I am writing some practice code in which I am trying to pass a string from one tab to another in a `UITabViewController` and using a label to display it in the next tab. Now the code where I am passing the message is:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
    MessageRecepientViewController * contoller = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    [contoller passString:_textField.text];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

And I am receiving the text here (in the second view controller) as:

```
-(void) passString:(NSString *) str
{
    _string = str;
}
```

And in `viewDidAppear`, i am doing this:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:_string];
    NSLog(@"did appear called, str = %@ and label text = %@", _string, self.textLabel.text);
}
```

and the log is showing that the value of the string is the passed text as it should be, but the value of textLabel.text is always null.

I have tried everything I could think of from checking that the UILabel is attached to the `textLabel` outlet to writing the code in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad but nothing have worked so far. The string is showing the correct value but the label is not updating. What is wrong here?

Comment: First off - [NSString stringWithString:_string]; is redundant - you can just go self.textLabel.text = _string;

Also try logging out the label to check it has been created. If it has'nt than it won't spring an error but it won't update either.

Comment: The second ViewController might not be loaded so far. The MessageRecepientViewController is receiving the message, but has no UIView to display the result.

Comment: Well I have logged the label and it is not yet created, how to wait till it is created? Normally when viewDidAppear is called everything is created. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the error:

It was a minor typo: I had declared `IBOutlet` as:

```
IBOutlet UILabel * textlabel;
```

and property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * textLabel;
```

and had attached the outlet to `textlabel` and had been updating `textLabel`. Fixed this and things are fine!